# In what order is the save(), clean(), delete() are called while saving a admin form in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have few models and in one of the models(say A) I have I have few foreign keys. For each foreign key I have an inline and a formset for each inline. I wanted to know in which order is the `save`, `clean` functions are called.

Comment: Didn't you find anything good in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/)?

Comment: Well, Django is OSS and so is `contrib.admin` so the quickest way to answer such a question is certainly to read the source (and eventually to trace it in a step debugger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have three models

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...

class Model2:
    model_1=models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    ...

Model3
    model_1=models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    ...
```

Now `Model1` has an admin with a form :

```
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    form = Model1AdminForm




class Model1AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    inlines = (Model2Inline, Model3Inline)

class Model2Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    form = Model2AdminForm
    formset = Model2AdminFormSet

class Model3Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    form = Model3AdminForm
    formset = Model3AdminFormSet
```

Here is the order of `save()`/`clean()` :

`Model1AdminForm's clean()` -> `Model2AdminForm's clean_fields()` -> `Model2AdminForm's clean()` -> `Model2AdminFormSet's clean()` -> `Model3AdminForm's clean_fields()` -> `Model3AdminForm's clean()` -> `Model3AdminFormSet's clean()` -> `Model1's save()` -> `Model2's save()` -> `Model3's save()`